# Attach second click-event to an element after class name has been changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `div` with a class name `a`. I attach a click-event to this div like

```
$('.a').on('click',  function() {
    $(this).removeClass('a').addClass('b');
})
```

After this; element's class name changes from `a` to `b`. I want to attach second click event on `.b` like

```
$('.b').on('click', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('b').addClass('c');
})
```

First click event works fine however second one does not fire. See my [JSfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/makqp941/)

Comment: Attach it to something outside of that object, then navigate into it.   So, lets say you have <div class='wrapper'> wrapped around it.  You use $('div.wrapper').on('click', 'div.b', function()......    http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2):

Attach the click even to a higher element in the DOM - when you change the class, the event bubbling up will change, e.g.

```
$("body").on("click", ".b", function() {
    $(this).removeClass('b').addClass('c');
});
```

Comment: This is the best answer, only the listeners for both `.a` and `.b` should be delegated, and @Paddy needs to fix the syntax. The event name is supposed to be the first parameter, and the selector second.

Comment: Also @Webber should be directed to some official learning resource regarding the matter, like the section on 'Direct and delegated events' in the jQuery documentation, http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @Thernys i already know answer has a syntax error. I tried it on my jsfiddle with correct syntax. Still does not work. Do you want to try it?

Comment: @Thernys Ah. i did not chang first one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add the second event after the first one has fired:

```
$('.a').on('click',  function() {
    $(this).removeClass('a').addClass('b');

    $('.b').on('click', function () { /* ... */ });
})
```

Comment: Why not just attach to `$(this)`, or rather chain the `.on`

Comment: It's not the same code - there may be more .b elements which OP wants to receive this new event, but only after an .a element has been clicked. I merely retained the OP's use case

Comment: Fair enough, though in that case this approach seems like a quick way to potentially flood a lot of elements (further assuming there are also many `.a` elements) with a lot of duplicate listeners, which is probably worth pointing out in case they ever do something other than replace a class on themselves.

Comment: You will get duplicate listeners using `$(this)` as well since the first event is not removed. Even the second click (which switches it from b to c) will bind a new click event to the same element. 

each click on the element will fire one more event than the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

You're running the .b code at the beginning, when the element doesn't have class b. Try adding the new onClick handler in the code for your first onClick.

Code:

```
$('.a').on('click',  function() {
$(this).removeClass('a').addClass('b');
        $('.b').on('click', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('b').addClass('c');
    })
})
```

Comment: wanna try on my JSfiddle??

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".a").click(function() {
 $(this).removeClass("a").addClass("b");
  $(".b").click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("b").addClass("c");
   })
})
```